# Question marked as "already answered", but the answer linked to does not answer my question

Tags: discussion, moderation

[XUbuntu 20.04 Network Device disconnecting every few minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391701/xubuntu-20-04-network-device-disconnecting-every-few-minutes-kernel-driver-e100)

The linked-to solution does not solve the problem. How can it be said that it has already been answered? Perhaps someone else with a similar problem had that solution work for them. I am having this problem, and that solution does not work for me. Unless I am improperly applying the proposed solution (I don't believe I am) this tells us that the problems are different.

Imagine PersonA posts about their printer not working, and then PersonB links to a thread where a printer was made to work by installing driver ABCD. PersonA then installs driver ABCD and their printer still doesn't work. Clearly, despite the problems appearing similar, the underlying cause of the problem is different. Otherwise, the solution would have worked.

My Ubuntu 20.04 machine broke after an update. I have not been able to fix that problem, despite trying all of the recommendations in that thread, including the false solution of installing "DKMS-based driver from https://github.com/koljah-de/e1000e-dkms-debian ."

I come here for help because this is a strange problem. The answer I get is that my question has already been solved, despite the fact that the proposed solution does not solve the problem?

Is this the community we want to be? Double-speak and false cures?

If the problem is not solved, the thread should not be closed. It should be left open so an answer can be potentially found, and so I can decide whether to use the bounty tool to generate attention to the question.

Comment: It seems the question has been reopened.

Comment: I'm not sure that throwing rocks ("*Double-speak and false cures*") is going to get a lot of help or support.

Comment: Maybe. Both were accurate and it's important to point out the problem in a clear way. It's a frustrating thing for a user to be told "your problem has been solved" when it hasn't been, and the site doesn't provide great or clear appeal tools for users.

Comment: I find it very frustrating when a question is marked as a duplicate and it is obvious, after perusing all the duplicate answers, that the persons flagging the question never read it and probably none of the duplicated questions or answers.